How to develop a 2D convection-diffusion component for mass transport
Update:
I followed Markus' comment and did a some modifications. More importantly, I added a Momentum Balance between the side ports. This allows to connect some of the elements in parallel and "distribute" the flow between them given different, eg., lengths. This is what I wanted but, unfortunately, the success in the simulation is very dependent on the mass flow rate that is being given as an input ("m" in the "simulationInputs" record element) and it doesn't work well for the ones that I am working on (2.5e-5 kg/s).
Also, when it works for some low mass flow rates variables such as velocities (in and out) have funny behaviors in time.
Any ideas on why could that be?
Finally, something that I figured out had to be done but I am not too happy about is the implementation of the Bernoulli principle.
As before, the package can be found here: link

I am working on a kind of plug flow reactor in which I have an unidirectional flow (let's say, from bottom to top), but there is also mass transfer due to diffusion on the sides with the adjacent components, as in the figure below.

I think I implemented correctly the model when connecting with other components acting as boundary conditions, but I am trying to develop it in a way that I could discretize the reactor to see how the concentration changes in different positions (eg, closer to a boundary vs in the "center" of the reactor), nevertheless, this is where I find issues.
My connector is defined as:
connector Port
  Modelica.Units.SI.Pressure p;
  flow Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate m;
  stream Modelica.Units.SI.Concentration c;
end Port;

and my "main element" is defined as:
model BasicElement
  Port north;
  Port south;
  Port west;
  Port east;
// "Made-up" variables
  Modelica.Units.SI.Mass m_cv;
  Modelica.Units.SI.Concentration c;
  Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate m_dot_c;
  Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho_in, rho_c, rho_out;
  Modelica.Units.SI.Velocity v_in, v_c, v_out;
  Real dp_cl(unit = "Pa/m");
  
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length l=1, w=1, d=1;
  parameter Real G = 0.005;                                  // Generation term
protected
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Area a_N = 1, a_S = 1, a_W = 1, a_E = 1;
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Volume V = l*w*d;
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DiffusionCoefficient diff = 1e-9;
  constant Modelica.Units.SI.MolarMass MM = 1/1000;
  constant Modelica.Units.SI.Acceleration g = 9.81;
  public
equation
//// ASSIGNMENTS TO "MADE-UP" VARIABLES ////
  rho_in = inStream(south.c)*MM;                    // densities
  rho_c = c*MM;
  rho_out = north.c*MM;

  m_dot_c = (south.m - north.m)/2;                 // mass flow

  v_c = m_dot_c/c/a_S/MM;                          // velocities
  v_in = south.m/inStream(south.c)/a_S/MM;

  dp_cl = (1/d)*(rho_c*(v_c^2)/2);                 // pressure loss

//// EQUATIONS ////
// Species conservation
  der(c) = (south.m/MM/a_S + north.m/MM/a_N)/l + (west.m/MM/a_W + east.m/MM/a_E)/w + G/MM/a_E/l;
// Mass conservation
  der(m_cv) = (south.m + north.m + west.m + east.m) + G;
// Mass flows
  north.m = -v_out*north.c*a_N*MM;
  east.m = -diff*(c - east.c)/(w/2)*a_E*MM;
  west.m = -diff*(west.c - c)/(w/2)*a_W*MM;
// MOMENTUM CONSERVATION
  l*der(m_dot_c) = (rho_in*a_S*v_in^2 - rho_out*a_N*v_out^2) - (north.p*a_N - south.p*a_S) - rho_c*g*l*((a_N + a_S)/2) - dp_cl*l*((a_N + a_S)/2);
// PRESSURE
  (south.p - north.p) = (m_dot_c^2)*l*dp_cl/((a_S^2)*(v_c^2))/(rho_c^2);
  west.p = north.p;
  east.p = north.p;
  c = (south.c + north.c)/2;
  south.c = inStream(south.c);
end BasicElement;


So basically I am implementing species conservation, mass conservation, defining the mass flows, and applying momentum conservation as explained here: Momentum balance.
Also, for simplicity, I am imposing that the pressures on the side connections are equal to the outlet.
I have made several examples which. Everything can be found in the following link: Link to package
The first test is to see how a simple element behaves with the input, output and boundary conditions on the sides.
The second test attempts to do what I desire, which is connect two of the basic elements side-by-side, but this is the one that gives me issues, more precisely:

[4] 15:58:18 Symbolic Error
Model is structurally singular, error found sorting equations
36: 0.0 = 0.0
for variables
6: basicElement1.rho_c:VARIABLE(min = 0.0 unit = "kg/m3" )  type: Real
[5] 15:58:18 Translation Error
Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!

Finally, the third test shows that the flow is separated appropriately in the two components, but each HAS to have the boundary conditions on the side, which is not what I desire.
I know this is not the way Modelica is intended to be used, as I am not making use of the Media or Fluid libraries, but it is the way I find best to understand.
Thanks in advance.

This is just an observation and not any answer. I ran the code through the JModelica compiler (after changes to MSL 3.2.2 by changing Unit.SI to SIunits). Test1 and Test3 goes through with warnings. But Test2 gives two compilation errors. "The following variable(s) could not be matched to any equation: basicElement.east.c, basicElement1.v_out" further "The following equation(s) could not be matched to any variable: basciElement.south.p - basciElement.west.p = basciElement1.m_dot_c ^2......". Does this give any new understanding?

I didn't thoroughly study the components to be honest, but Dymola reports the following for Test2:
Circular equalities detected.
The equations
basicElement1.north.p = basicElement.north.p;
basicElement1.west.p = basicElement1.north.p;
basicElement1.west.p = basicElement.east.p;
basicElement.east.p = basicElement.north.p; 

From a quick look at the code, I could imagine the equations
west.p = north.p;
east.p = north.p;

being the issue.
My thoughts: The connect-statements will set potential variables (=Modelica.Units.SI.Pressure p;) to equal values. As they have the same value set in the model as well, this could result in the "circular equalities" reported above. It could help to add a resisitive element between the two connectors or instead of setting the pressure directly, define a relation between potential and flow variable for the ports.
The above would also explain why Test3 works, as it removes the equations generated by the connect statements which result in the circular equality...

Markus, thanks for the input. It made a lot of sense and I actually worked on it. I figured that maybe a Momentum balance should be applied between east and west ports, so I did. Also, I had to include Bernoulli principle between south and north, and west and east. I am not too happy about it as I feel that I need a better justification for it, but it made it work, but unfortunately with some details that I explained in an edit to the original post

Not sure what to do here to be honest (I'm not into fluids so much). Did you try the nominal attribute on variables with low values? That could help the numeric solver and would be rather simple to test...
